# How do I deploy my Angular App to different firebase environments?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I want to have my angular app running on two different websites, one for development/showcase purposes, one for production.

For that, I created two firebase projects (app and appDev) each with it's own realtime database.

How do I correctly deploy my app to those environments? Do I need to use firebase CLI or angular CLI?

I found about the angular src/environments folder, which contains my environment.ts and environment.prod.ts - but actually it seems to not change a thing, I can put faulty data to that file and it will still correctly deploy to my dev environment (which I initially configured ng add @angular/fire) and run with the dev DB.

I also found about firebase targets, but they seem quite mighty (with different ressource types and stuff) for what I want to achieve and I probably couldn't use ng deploy then, so I am unsure if this is the right direction.

A third method seems to be "firebase use --add" and adding multiple projects.

Right now I can reinitialize firebase any time I want to switch, this works but it can't be thought like this. Any pointers? What is the supposed difference between the environments and the targets and the projects?

Answer (score 0):

In file angular.json
Ex:
"configurations":

```
    { "staging": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ]
    },
    "demo": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.demo.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ]
    },
```

src/environments/environment.staging.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://firebase/api'
};
```

Model:

```
import {environment} from './environments/environment';

this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/some/select_options`, { params })
      .pipe();
```

And build or run:

```
ng build --configuration=staging
```